# Why can I use a variable in an assignment to that same variable in an object literal, but it creates a self-reference in a function literal?

Tags: javascript

How come I can recycle a variable in an object literal like this:

```
var x=1;
x={
a:x;
}
console.log(x.a);//1
```

but not in a function literal

```
var y=2;
y=()=>y;
console.log(y()); //y() //?? why not 2?
console.log(y()()()()()()); //y()
```

The x case works whether x was initially a primitive or not. The y case appears to work the same with an arrow function or a standard one.

I was using the x case without issue for a method that takes either an object as a param, or a string (which it then converts to an object). I had a similar situation for functions (if y is a string, make it into a function returning that string) but it doesn't work the same way.

I know I can make y work with something like

```
var y=2;
let val=y;
y=()=>val;
console.log(y());//2
```

But i don't know why it's necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to an already excellent answer,  a closure could be used to "make it work" by storing the current value of y in the scope chain of the function assigned to y:

```
y = (x=>()=>x)(y);
```

In brief, calling `(x=>()=>x)` with `y` first sets the parameter value `x` to `y`, and then returns a nested function that returns the value of `x` in its outer scope.

More complex closures are commonly used in asynchronous code to reference and update the values of variables and parameters defined in outer functions at the time a nested function was created.

Comment: this lets me keep it as a 1 liner, which is fantastic

Comment: FWIW, the original code already uses a closure. What you added was a *function call* to create a new scope to capture the current value of `y`.

Answer (score 2):

It's all about *when* the variable is evaluated.

When you do

```
x={
a:x;
}
```

then the current value of `x` is read at that moment, assigned to the property `a` and finally the new object is assigned to `x`.

I.e. the evaluation of `x` happens **before** the new value is assigned to `x`.

In

```
y=()=>y;
```

the variable (`y`) inside the function is not evaluated *until the function is called*, which happens later.

I.e. the evaluation of `y` happens **after** the new value was assigned to `y`.

---

The fact that you are overwriting existing variables makes this a bit more difficult to follow. Lets look at a simpler example:

```
var x = 42;
var obj = {a: x};
x = 21;
// logs 42 because that was the value of `x` at the moment the object was created
console.log(obj.a);


var y = 42;
var f = () => y;
y = 21;
// logs 21 because at the moment the function is called, the value of `y` has already 
// been updated
console.log(f());
```